# Выравнивание заголовков

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать, чтобы заголовки были на одном уровне друг под другом ? Я понимаю,что причина в том,что разный размер картинок.Но если я делаю одинаковый размер для них,то у картинки теряется качество. Как решить данную проблему ? Может быть картинку в одну строку надо ставить не таким образом, а как-нибудь иначе ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.feature__title-second{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #0f5f5c;
 display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 22px;
}

.feature__text-second{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #83a7a5;
 line-height: 22px;
 width: 513px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
           <div class="feature__block-second">
              <img src="img/icon4.png" alt="icon" class="feature__icon ">
             <h3 class="feature__title-second">
                Cross Browser Compatibility
             </h3>
             <p class="feature__text-second">
               Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
             </p>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-6">
           <div class="feature__block-second">
              <img src="img/icon5.png" alt="icon" class="feature__icon ">
             <h3 class="feature__title-second">
                Cross Browser Compatibility
             </h3>
             <p class="feature__text-second">
               Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
             </p>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-6">
           <div class="feature__block-second">
              <img src="img/icon6.png" alt="icon" class="feature__icon ">
             <h3 class="feature__title-second">
                Cross Browser Compatibility
             </h3>
             <p class="feature__text-second">
               Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
             </p>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-6">
           <div class="feature__block-second">
              <img src="img/icon7.png" alt="icon" class="feature__icon ">
             <h3 class="feature__title-second">
                Cross Browser Compatibility
             </h3>
             <p class="feature__text-second">
               Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
             </p>
           </div>
         </div>
        
       </div>
```

Comment: Вокруг картинки добавьте див, с фиксированной шириной и display: inline-block. Если нужен пример кода, то смогу написать через пол часа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как писал в комменте, засылаю пример кода. На место иконок - подставьте свои, без указывания ширины. Ширина в .ico должна быть по самой большой иконке.

```css
.feature__title-second{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #0f5f5c;
 display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 22px;
}

.feature__text-second{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #83a7a5;
 line-height: 22px;
 width: 513px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.ico {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
           <div class="feature__block-second">
           <div class="ico"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/70/70358.png" style="width: 30px" alt="icon" class="feature__icon "></div>
             <h3 class="feature__title-second">
                Cross Browser Compatibility
             </h3>
             <p class="feature__text-second">
               Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
             </p>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-6">
           <div class="feature__block-second">
              <div class="ico">
              
              <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/70/70358.png" style="width: 10px" alt="icon" class="feature__icon ">
              </div>
             <h3 class="feature__title-second">
                Cross Browser Compatibility
             </h3>
             <p class="feature__text-second">
               Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
             </p>
           </div>
         </div>
        

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я еще после вашего комментария сделал, как вы сказали и все получилось :)

Comment: Может кому-то еще поможет :)